# No module named 'kiwisolver' when trying to import matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pycharm

I am trying to plot some data in Python and therefore require matplotlib.
When trying to import it, I get the `ModuleNotFoundError`.

My line that raises the error is

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

My installed packages include (according to PyCharm's Python Interpreter Menu):

```
matplotlib==3.3.4
numpy==1.20.1
pandas==1.4.3
kiwisolver==1.3.1
```

The stack trace shows

```
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/user/pycharm/ai_ems/data/data_classes/load/electrical/fit_compressor_data.py", line 3, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\pycharm\ai_ems\ems-gym\venv_ems-gym\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 174, in <module>
    _check_versions()
  File "C:\Users\user\pycharm\ai_ems\ems-gym\venv_ems-gym\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 168, in _check_versions
    module = importlib.import_module(modname)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kiwisolver'
```

Comment: Yup, apparently they are. but after finding this : https://github.com/nucleic/kiwi/issues/68   I uninstalled and reinstalled kiwisolver, and for some reason it works now

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After finding this: https://github.com/nucleic/kiwi/issues/68:

I uninstalled and reinstalled kiwisolver, and for some reason it works now.

Comment: In my case I just needed to uninstall it; the reinstall said `Requirement already satisfied`.  I had installed matplotlib via conda, but the fix was to uninstall via pip (the pip in the conda environment).  So all I had to do was `pip uninstall kiwisolver` from within my conda environment.